# Is there a way to configure where Xcode puts its temporary data?

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to save my SSD from unnecessary write-cycles. 
Is there a way to configure Xcode to put temp files to the specified directory on the external drive?
I have the same question about Unity3d and Photoshop. 
Is there any general option to configure cache\temporary data location for all soft?

Comment: You should have seperate your question in three threads with the appropriate tags. A Xcode user don't need to know anything about Photoshop or Unity and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what temporary data you mean, however you can configure a fair amount of the locations in Xcode.

I configure this specifically to use my `~/tmp` folder, where I can see what it's produced, in order to clean-up *Derived Data* or copy products from the *Archive* folder, rather than rummage around `~/Library/Application Support/`, or wherever the default location is:

[image]

Comment: And for Photoshop; Photoshop Menu > Preferences > Performance > it's under "Scratch Disks" if you have a valid drive connected.

Comment: 1. About Xcode - is it for temp files (like temp directory in windows or /appdata) or for project files?
2. Thanks for answer about Photoshop.
3. It it possible for Unity3d?

Comment: @user2553675 Are you talking about my `~/tmp` directory?  If so, then yes, this is a general junk directory for my personal use.  As far as Photoshop and Unity3D, then sorry I've no idea.